# Bytes Accessor in Wireshark in c

Tags: c, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I've to access 4 bytes of data from tvb (tvbuff_t *) passed in 
dissect-protocolname() function. 
I used 2 functions:
     `1. data = tvb_get_bits32(tvb, offset, 32, ENC_BIG_ENDIAN);
 2. proto_tree_add_item(foo_tree, hf_foo_data, tvb, offset, 4, ENC_BIG_ENDIAN);`

the returned value from the first function i'm displaying it using

```
proto_tree_add_uint(foo_tree, hf_foo_data1, tvb, offset, 4, data);
```

Both shows the different result in second display pane of wireshark. I'm not changing the offset too.
since offset does not change in both and both are accessing 4 bytes of data . Then Why do both show different result ?
I need 4 bytes of data in a variable to manipulate which first function is  doing but returned value is not correct why ??
second function shows the correct decimal value of 4 bytes in display pane of wireshark whereas first does not, why ?
Is there any other function to access more than 1 byte of data(eg: 4 byte) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because the second argument of `tvb_get_bits32()` where you pass in `offset` needs to be the offset in number of **bits**, not bytes; whereas the similar offset fourth argument for `proto_tree_add_item()` should be the number of bytes not bits.

That's why the second argument in the declaration for `tvb_get_bits32()` is called "**`bit_offset`**", not "`offset`".

The idea is that when you want to extract/dissect specific bits from the tvbuf, then you'll likely want to start somewhere in the middle of a byte.

In your case, if you want all 32 bits from the byte boundary at `offset`, then do this:

```
data = tvb_get_bits32(tvb, offset * 8, 32, ENC_BIG_ENDIAN);
```